# Conflito jQuery com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Estou tendo um problema com `AngularJS` e `jQuery`. Quando uso somente o jQuery no layout, o menu (sidebar) que tenho ele abre normalmente. Mas quando adiciono o AngularJS o menu não abre mais, fica simplesmente fechado. O ruim disso tudo é que no console não me apresenta nenhum erro.

O código do Menu

```
  <!-- BEGIN SIDEBPANEL-->
  <nav class="page-sidebar" data-pages="sidebar" pg-sidebar>
    <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR MENU TOP TRAY CONTENT-->
    <div class="sidebar-overlay-slide from-top" id="appMenu">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding">
          <a href="" class="p-l-40">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/imagens/extra.svg')?>" width="83" height="83" alt="socail">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding">
          <a href="" class="p-l-10">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/imagens/extra.svg')?>" width="83" height="83" alt="socail">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 m-t-20 no-padding">
          <a href="" class="p-l-40">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/imagens/extra.svg')?>" width="83" height="83" alt="socail">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 m-t-20 no-padding">
          <a href="" class="p-l-10">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/imagens/extra.svg')?>" width="83" height="83" alt="socail">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END SIDEBAR MENU TOP TRAY CONTENT-->
    <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR MENU HEADER-->
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/logo_white.png')?>" alt="logo" class="brand" data-src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/logo_white.png')?>" ui-jq="unveil" data-src-retina="<?php base_url('assets/img/logo_white_2x.png')?>" width="78" height="32">
      <div class="sidebar-header-controls">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs sidebar-slide-toggle btn-link m-l-20" data-pages-toggle="#appMenu"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fs-16"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link visible-lg-inline" data-toggle-pin="sidebar"><i class="fa fs-12"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END SIDEBAR MENU HEADER-->
    <!-- START SIDEBAR MENU -->
    <div class="sidebar-menu">
      <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR MENU ITEMS-->
      <ul class="menu-items">
        <li class="pointer m-t-30 open" ui-sref-active="active">
          <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard" class="detailed"><span class="title">Dashboard</span></a>
          <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="pg-home"></i></span>
        </li>

        <li class="open active">
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <span class="title">Business Intelligence</span>
                <span class=" open  arrow"></span>
            </a>
            <span class="icon-thumbnail">
                <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
            </span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>BI_sellin"><small>Sell In Panel</small></a>
                    <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i></span>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>BI_analise"><small>Business Overview</small></a>
                    <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="pointer" >
          <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>visao"><span class="title">Visão</span></a>
          <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>
        </li>
<!--        
        <li class="pointer open">
          <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>ClimaAdmin" class="detailed"><span class="title">Clima</span></a>
          <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i></span>
        </li>
-->
        <!-- OLD -->
        <li style="visibility: hidden">
          <a href="javascript:;"><span class="title">Lixeira</span>
          <span class=" arrow"></span></a>
          <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="pg-trash"></i></span>
          <ul class="sub-menu">


                <li class="pointer" >
                  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>warmap"><span class="title">WarMap</span></a>
                  <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="fa fa-map-signs"></i></span>
                </li>
                <li class="pointer" >
                  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>visao"><span class="title">Visão</span></a>
                  <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>
                </li>
                <li class="pointer" >
                  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>distribuidores"><span class="title">Distribuidores</span></a>
                  <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i></span>
                </li>
                <li class="pointer" >
                  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>chart"><span class="title">Gráficos YTD/YTG</span></a>
                  <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="fa fa-pie-chart"></i></span>
                </li>
                <li class="pointer">
                  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>SOP"><span class="title">SOP</span></a>
                  <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"></i></span>
                </li> 
                <li class="pointer" >
                  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>analise_situacao_cadastral"><span class="title">Análise</span></a>
                  <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="fa fa-user-secret"></i></span>
                </li>
                <li class="pointer">
                  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>construcao"><span class="title">CRM</span></a>
                  <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>
                </li>
                <li class="pointer">
                  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>construcao"><span class="title">VANT</span></a>
                  <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="fa fa-fighter-jet"></i></span>
                </li>  
                <li class="pointer">
                  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>construcao"><span class="title">Clima</span></a>
                  <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i></span>
                </li>  
                <li class="pointer">
                  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>db"><span class="title">DB Compare</span></a>
                  <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="fa fa-database"></i></span>
                </li> 


          </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- .OLD -->
      </ul>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- END SIDEBAR MENU -->
  </nav>
  <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
  <!-- END SIDEBPANEL-->
```

Comment: Por quê tu não usa só um? Misturar os dois é uma péssima escolha.

Comment: Usar os dois juntos é pedir pra fazer a aplicação sair faíscas. Vai ter mais problemas contornando a situação do que escolhendo ficar com um só.

Comment: Espera, vamos pensar bem no que você esta fazendo... você esta usando Angular + JQuery + PHP, por que? Se você for usar o PHP  para manipular valores no DOM e for usar JQuery para fazer a manipulação do DOM, o Angular fica totalmente inútil, não faz o menor sentido você carregar ele nesse cenário, a única coisa que vai fazer é gerar erros, lentidão e consumir banda de dados a mais do seu usuário.

Comment: Na verdade precisei usar o AngularJS para fazer um código, adaptei da internet, mas como o tema usa jQuery então o menu parou de abrir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um problema comum é a ordem que os js são injetados no html, jquery com angularjs funciona... 

Se não me engano o angular deve ser declarado antes do jquery.

O próprio angular já tem uma  "mini" [biblioteca do Jquery](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

Comment: Darei sua resposta como certa, pois foi mais ou menos isso que fiz, mas coloquei os arquivos do angular do tema perto da onde as requisições do AngularJS estão sendo executadas.